# CallKit - where are numbers loaded for blocking or id stored?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, telephony, callkit

I'm in the process of implementing a CallKit extension to our app to block and / or ID certain numbers.  Management is concerned that the numbers loaded with the

```
CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:)
```

(and the one for ID'ing certain numbers) can be accessed by outside parties.

So, the specific question is where do these numbers get stored by the `CallKit` framework and b) can someone theoretically access those numbers (with either a normal phone or a `jailbroken` one)?

I've read a blurb somewhere stating that the numbers are stored in a SQLite database, but again, can't confirm this - nor can I confirm any type of encryption or what not.

Many thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2):

CallKit will not store your blocking phone numbers anywhere in the iOS system.

From Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) under **Blocking Incoming calls**

> When a phone receives an incoming call, the system first consults the
>   user’s block list to determine whether a call should be blocked. If
>   the phone number is not on a user- or system-defined block list, the
>   system then consults your app’s Call Directory extension to find a
>   matching blocked number.

So it is clear that CallKit will consult with your Call Directory extension to find a matching blocked number. The list of blocked phone number should be stored in your containing app and It is up to us to decide how to store the data in our containing app. The ideal way is to store it in some sort of DB/CoreData.

In terms of security, if the phone is jailbroken, anyone can access the app data. To avoid it you can encrypt the data before storing in DB/CoreData.